# Sticked table columns and header with horizontal and vertical scrolling in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am completely new to AngularJS, HTML, JS, CSS, even web development. For days, i'have been trying to implement a scenario, where:

I have a table, where columns have dynamic width. The table header needs to be sticked (or always on screen), as well as the first two columns. The table has to be able to scroll horizontally and vertically.

What I did, it has several problems, and because I am new to this, i am stucked here. I can implement the sticked header, OR the sticked first two columns, but not both. They also not 'wired' together.

Here is what  I did. CSS is mainly from another soucre.

```js
function StickController($scope) {
    $scope.dataset = {
       tabledata: [
        {
        col1: 'col1',
        col2: 'col2',
        col3: 'col3',
        col4: 'col4 Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem ',
        col5: 'col5',
        col6: 'col6',
        col7: 'col7',
        col8: 'col8',
        col9: 'col9',
        col10: 'col10',
        col11: 'col11',
        col12: 'col12',
        col13: 'col13'
        
        },{
         col1: 'col1',
        col2: 'col2',
        col3: 'col3',
        col4: 'col4',
        col5: 'col5',
        col6: 'col6',
        col7: 'col7',
        col8: 'col8',
        col9: 'col9',
        col10: 'col10',
        col11: 'col11',
        col12: 'col12 Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem',
        col13: 'col13'
        },{
         col1: 'col1',
        col2: 'col2',
        col3: 'col3',
        col4: 'col4',
        col5: 'col5',
        col6: 'col6',
        col7: 'col7',
        col8: 'col8',
        col9: 'col9',
        col10: 'col10',
        col11: 'col11',
        col12: 'col12',
        col13: 'col13'
        },{
         col1: 'col1',
        col2: 'col2',
        col3: 'col3',
        col4: 'col4',
        col5: 'col5',
        col6: 'col6',
        col7: 'col7',
        col8: 'col8 Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem',
        col9: 'col9',
        col10: 'col10',
        col11: 'col11',
        col12: 'col12',
        col13: 'col13'
        },{
         col1: 'col1',
        col2: 'col2',
        col3: 'col3',
        col4: 'col4',
        col5: 'col5',
        col6: 'col6',
        col7: 'col7',
        col8: 'col8',
        col9: 'col9',
        col10: 'col10',
        col11: 'col11',
        col12: 'col12',
        col13: 'col13'
        },{
         col1: 'col1',
        col2: 'col2',
        col3: 'col3',
        col4: 'col4 Lorem LoremLoremLorem Lorem Lorem LoremLorem ',
        col5: 'col5',
        col6: 'col6',
        col7: 'col7',
        col8: 'col8',
        col9: 'col9',
        col10: 'col10',
        col11: 'col11',
        col12: 'col12',
        col13: 'col13'
        },{
         col1: 'col1',
        col2: 'col2',
        col3: 'col3',
        col4: 'col4',
        col5: 'col5',
        col6: 'col6',
        col7: 'col7',
        col8: 'col8',
        col9: 'col9',
        col10: 'col10',
        col11: 'col11',
        col12: 'col12',
        col13: 'col13'
        },{
         col1: 'col1',
        col2: 'col2',
        col3: 'col3',
        col4: 'col4',
        col5: 'col5',
        col6: 'col6',
        col7: 'col7',
        col8: 'col8',
        col9: 'col9',
        col10: 'col10',
        col11: 'col11',
        col12: 'col12',
        col13: 'col13'
        },{
         col1: 'col1',
        col2: 'col2',
        col3: 'col3',
        col4: 'col4',
        col5: 'col5',
        col6: 'col6',
        col7: 'col7',
        col8: 'col8',
        col9: 'col9',
        col10: 'col10',
        col11: 'col11',
        col12: 'col12',
        col13: 'col13'
        }
        ]
    };
}
```

```css
table {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.stick-table {
    border: none;
    border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.stick-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    border: none;
    color: #336B6B;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Bookman", Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
}
.stick-table tbody td {
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Bookman", Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
    border: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
}
.stick-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.stick-scroller {
    margin-left: 160px;
    overflow-y: visible;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.stick-table .stick-sticky-col {
    border-left: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    left: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: auto;
    height: 20px;
    width: 90px;
}
.stick-table .stick-sticky-col-kat {
    border-left: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    left: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: auto;
    height: 20px;
    width: 40px;
}
.stick-table .stick-sticky-col-edit {
    border-left: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    height: 20px;
    width: 30px;
}
.stick-scroller-client {
    margin-left: 30px;
    overflow-y: visible;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller='StickController'>
<p>
This content should not be scrolled either way.
</p>
<div class="stick-wrapper">
        <div class="stick-scroller">
            <table class="stick-table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="stick-sticky-col">SCol1</th>
                    <th class="stick-sticky-col-kat">SCol2</th>
                    <th>Col3</th>
                    <th>Col4</th>
                    <th>Col5</th>
                    <th>Col6</th>
                    <th>Col7</th>
                    <th>Col8</th>
                    <th>Col9</th>
                    <th>Col10</th>
                    <th>Col11</th>
                    <th>Col12</th>
                    <th>Col13</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in dataset.tabledata">
                    <td class="stick-sticky-col">{{ data.col1 }}</td>
                    <!--<td>{{ car.allapot }}</td>-->
                    <td class="stick-sticky-col-kat">{{ data.col2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.col3 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.col4}}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.col5 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.col6 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.col7 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.col8 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.col9 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.col10 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.col11 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.col12}}</td>
                    <td>{{ data.col13 }}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I have created  a fiddle, that's where I am now.
Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/2590/

I've never used jQuery, can I solve this problem only with css?
Please keep in mind that I have never done web development before, i tried my best here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

HI try add `overflow auto` on outer div here is the work fiddle

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/2592/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have no experience with jQuery/Angular try using any of tables plugins, https://www.datatables.net/ or https://www.dynatable.com for example.

Just don't write you own code, but try to folloew one of the relevant examples they have - https://www.datatables.net/examples/index. That may solve you case faster then diving into Angular/jQuery coding.